# Property of spectrum of a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Recall that $\textrm{Spec}(R)$ is the set of prime ideals of $R$. Further, recall that if $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq R$ is an ideal then \begin{equation}V(\mathfrak{a})=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(R):\mathfrak{p}\supset\mathfrak{a}\}.\end{equation} Prove that \begin{equation}\bigcap_{i\in I}V(\mathfrak{a}_i)=V\left(\sum_i\mathfrak{a}_i\right).\end{equation}

My attempt: By the above definition, we have \begin{equation}V(\mathfrak{a}_i)=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(R):\mathfrak{p}\supset\mathfrak{a}_i\},\end{equation}
that is, the intersection is the set of $\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(R)$ which contain all of the $\mathfrak{a}_i$. But why does this give the sum on the RHS?

Comment: Any ideal (not even necessary prime) contains all of the ideals in the collection $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ if and only if it contains their sum $\sum\limits_{i\in I} a_i$. This is what you have to prove. I will leave the proof to you, because you clearly should be able to do that if you know all the definitions.